# Opencart payment gateway development

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart-module, opencart2.3

Can anyone give me the tools or guidelines necessary to create a custom payment gateway? For my school assignment, I've been tasked with developing an opencart (2.3.0.2) payment gateway. I've done some research but I'm completely lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: schools are harsh nowadays...

Answer (score 1):

For creating a payment gateway in opencart, you will have to create an **extension/module**. You can have a look at this tutorial :

[Creating Payment method in Opencart](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-payment-method-in-opencart-part-1--cms-22338)

It is a three part series read it once to understand and then you can explore the documentation of opencart to create one.

Every payment gateway provides provides API key to interact with their system regarding the order queries.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Every payment gateway in OpenCart contains his own model and controller, there are a lot of examples that can be found [here](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/tree/master/upload/catalog/model/extension/payment) and [here](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/tree/master/upload/catalog/controller/extension/payment). You'll need to take a look at [this controller](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/checkout/payment_method.php) as well, it contains the methods to gather payment methods at the checkout.

Take a look at this codes, and table structure when you have questions about specific subjects feel free to ask.

Comment: @StephonDuncan still you have a lot of information if you look at the links, there are examples in there, I am not going to write you code. For redirecting and everything with responses you can look at the response class of OpenCart (https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/response.php)